# Pass current model to as a ConverterParameter via xamarin binding

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

Writing `ConverterParameter={Binding}` within ListView's DataTemplate passes an empty Xamarin.Forms.Binding object instead of current model.

this is my code:

```
IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.CardLoc, Source={x:Reference this} ,Converter={StaticResource MenuItemToIsVisibleReverseConverter} , ConverterParameter={Binding} "
```

everythings works fine except   `ConverterParameter={Binding}`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Xamarin Forms doesn't support bindable properties within `ConverterParameter`.  One workaround is to pass a reference to an element on your page and access it's `BindingContext` in order to get the view model property you're looking for.

For example your binding statement:

```
IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.CardLoc, Source={x:Reference this} ,Converter={StaticResource MenuItemToIsVisibleReverseConverter} , ConverterParameter={x:Reference SomeElementOnPage} "
```

Within your converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var viewModel = ((SomeElementOnPage)parameter).BindingContext as YourViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got to pass by reference like :

```
<Element
      Attribute="{Binding Value,
      Converter={StaticResource YourConverter},
      ConverterParameter={x:reference CompareTo}}" />
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need to pass the current object by putting a `.`

So it would be `ConverterParameter={Binding .}`

Comment: No way bro , no way

Answer (score -3):

Here is how to pass command parameter to viewmodel and view .

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell 
                    Text="{Binding FirstName}" 
                    Detail="{Binding LastName}" 
                >
                    <TextCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem 
                            Text="Apagar"
                            IsDestructive="true"
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference ContactView}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                        />
                    </TextCell.ContextActions>
                </TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Nooooo, I mean exactly ConverterParameter and not  CommandParameter , CommandParameter  works yes, but ConverterParameter not.

Comment: check this link will work for you-https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71810/pass-binding-to-converterparameter

Comment: Label is passed as converter parameter but it's text property is null while I wrote: Text="{Binding Price}" , Price is current models's property, why?

Comment: sorry your question is not clear please send and edit proper question

Comment: I removed ConverterParameter and found another solution without it. Thank you very much for your answers and hope they will fix it in next versions.